# How to update this VBA code to include a google maps API key

Tags: excel, vba, api, google-maps

I am new to VBA but I am trying to update an Excel spreadsheet that calculates distances between two points. this code used to work (as far as I know) but now requires a  Google API key. I have my API key ready to go but not sure how to implement it into this code. I could use a little guidance.

(sorry for the wall of code I wasn't sure what to include so I copy/pasted everything)

````
Option Explicit

Function G_DISTANCE( _
    Origin As String, _
    Destination As String, _
    Optional Requery As Boolean = False _
    ) As Variant
' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0

Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim distanceNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim statusNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim CachedFile As String
Dim NoCache As Boolean
    On Error GoTo exitRoute
    G_DISTANCE = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' Return an #N/A error in the case of any errors

    ' Check and clean inputs
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Origin) _
        Or IsEmpty(Origin) _
        Or Origin = "" Then GoTo exitRoute
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Destination) _
        Or IsEmpty(Destination) _
        Or Destination = "" Then GoTo exitRoute
    Origin = URLEncode(CStr(Origin), True)
    Destination = URLEncode(CStr(Destination), True)

    ' Check for existence of cached file
    CachedFile = Environ("temp") & "\" & Origin & "_" & Destination & "_Dist.xml"
    NoCache = (Len(Dir(CachedFile)) = 0)

    Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    If NoCache Or Requery Then ' if no cached file exists then query Google
        ' Read the XML data from the Google Maps API
        myRequest.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" _
            & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&sensor=false", False
        myRequest.send


    Else ' otherwise query the temp file
        myRequest.Open "GET", CachedFile
        myRequest.send
        Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
        myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText
        ' Get the status code of the cached XML file in case of previously cached errors
        Set statusNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//status")
        If Not statusNode.Text = "OK" Then
            Call G_DISTANCE(Origin, Destination, True) ' Recursive way to try to remove cached errors
        End If
    End If

    ' Make the XML readable using XPath
    Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
    myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText

    ' If statusNode is "OK" then get the values to return
    Set statusNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//status")
    If statusNode.Text = "OK" Then
        If NoCache Then: Call CreateFile(CachedFile, myRequest.responseText) ' Cache API response if required
        ' Get the distance
        Set distanceNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/distance/value")
        If Not distanceNode Is Nothing Then G_DISTANCE = val(distanceNode.Text) / 1000 ' Now works with comma as decimal separator
    Else
        G_DISTANCE = statusNode.Text
    End If
exitRoute:
    ' Tidy up
    Set statusNode = Nothing
    Set distanceNode = Nothing
    Set myDomDoc = Nothing
    Set myRequest = Nothing
End Function
```

```vba
Function G_DURATION( _
    Origin As String, _
    Destination As String, _
    Optional Requery As Boolean = False _
    ) As Variant
' Requires a reference to Microsoft XML, v6.0
' Dependencies:
' Encode_URL
' Utilities_Files.Create_File

' Updated 30/10/2012 to
'   - return an #N/A error if an error occurs
'   - cache if necessary
'   - check for and attempt to correct cached errors
'   - work on systems with comma as decimal separator

Dim myRequest As XMLHTTP60
Dim myDomDoc As DOMDocument60
Dim durationNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim statusNode As IXMLDOMNode
Dim CachedFile As String
Dim NoCache As Boolean
    On Error GoTo exitRoute
    G_DURATION = CVErr(xlErrNA) ' Return an #N/A error in the case of any errors

    ' Check and clean inputs
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Origin) _
        Or IsEmpty(Origin) _
        Or Origin = "" Then GoTo exitRoute
    If WorksheetFunction.IsNumber(Destination) _
        Or IsEmpty(Destination) _
        Or Destination = "" Then GoTo exitRoute
    Origin = ConvertAccent(URLEncode(CStr(Origin), True))
    Destination = ConvertAccent(URLEncode(CStr(Destination), True))

    ' Check for existence of cached file
    CachedFile = Environ("temp") & "\" & Origin & "_" & Destination & "_Dist.xml"
    NoCache = (Len(Dir(CachedFile)) = 0)

    Set myRequest = New XMLHTTP60

    If NoCache Or Requery Then ' if no cached file exists then query Google
        ' Read the XML data from the Google Maps API
        myRequest.Open "GET", "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" _
            & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&sensor=false", False
        myRequest.send
    Else ' otherwise query the temp file
        myRequest.Open "GET", CachedFile
        myRequest.send
        Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
        myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText
        ' Get the status code of the cached XML file in case of previously cached errors
        Set statusNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//status")
        If Not statusNode.Text = "OK" Then
            Call G_DURATION(Origin, Destination, True) ' Recursive way to try to remove cached errors
        End If
    End If

    ' Make the XML readable using XPath
    Set myDomDoc = New DOMDocument60
    myDomDoc.LoadXML myRequest.responseText

    ' If statusNode is "OK" then get the values to return
    Set statusNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//status")
    If statusNode.Text = "OK" Then
        If NoCache Then: Call CreateFile(CachedFile, myRequest.responseText) ' Cache API response if required
        ' Get the duration
        Set durationNode = myDomDoc.SelectSingleNode("//leg/duration/value")
        If Not durationNode Is Nothing Then G_DURATION = val(durationNode.Text) / 60 ' Now works with comma as decimal separator
    End If

exitRoute:
    ' Tidy up
    Set statusNode = Nothing
    Set durationNode = Nothing
    Set myDomDoc = Nothing
    Set myRequest = Nothing
End Function
````

Comment: *sorry for the wall of code i wasn't sure what to include so i copy and pasted everything* - the idea of a [mcve] is that you *don't* post your full code, just an example that reproduces the problem with minimal code.

Comment: I'm not sure if things have moved on but IIRC the beta release required you to display maps along with using the service.  That aside.... the documentation seems pretty clear on where you put your API key: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start   ( example is json but I think it likely xml will have same construct as it is querystring.) I suggest you try implementing just that part as a simple GET request and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your API key to a `key` parameter in your Directions API request. Also note that the `sensor` parameter is deprecated. So what you can easily do here is replace it with the key. As an additional side-note, the call should always be made over HTTPS if possible.

See below:

```
If NoCache Or Requery Then ' if no cached file exists then query Google
    ' Read the XML data from the Google Maps API
    myRequest.Open "GET", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=" _
        & Origin & "&destination=" & Destination & "&key=AIza...", False
    myRequest.send
Else ' otherwise query the temp file
```

Where "AIza..." should be your own project's API key (which I suggest you add as a previously defined variable). For your reference take a look at [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key#add_key).

Make sure that both Billing and Directions API are enabled on your project.

Hope this helps!